# Kali Linux app is showing errors while opening on Windows 11

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, windows-11

Ubuntu is successfully installed and running fine.And while running kali linux, this pops up and disappears upon clicking any key.

Tried re-installing linux, wsl --shutdown and than re-doing all. On my previous attempt of installing kali-linus, installing went smooth & upon running "kex --win -s", it showed nothing but a blank page.

Now upon opening kali linux, it shows this error.[As described](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmLnc.png)